# Show view record by using curls

Tags: php, json, curl

Show view record by using curl

I have try this code but not got any reponse

```
$pro_url = 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/western-states-healthcare-group-2-0/view/Providers_Report?authtoken=b627006529f0d19852608be37d4bdf85&zc_ownername=nmormond&criteria=(Provider_Name=="Injury%20Treatment%20Centers%20Redwood")&scope=creatorapi';

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_URL, $pro_url);

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// Turn off the server and peer verification 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//Set to return data to string ($response) 

$datapro = curl_exec($checkpro);

echo "<pre>";print_r($datapro);
```

But, i want this output

```
var zohonmormondview244 = {"Providers":[{"ZIP":"84123-6799","Provider_Type_Temp":"","Address_Line_1":"6321 S. Redwood Rd 105","Address_Line_2":"","Main_Fax":"801-904-3435","Website":"","Main_Phone":"801 904 3089","City":"Taylorsville","Provider_Name":"Injury Treatment Centers Redwood","State_Temp":"","Signed_POA":"No","Reimbursement_Rate":55,"In_Network":"Yes","State":"Utah","Signed_Purchae_Agreement":"Yes","VAR_Provider_Type":"PT / Chiro","Signed_HIPAA":"Yes","ID":"977948000005031127","Notes":""}]};
```

Comment: Actually the link you provided is a download file link so you can't do it with curl

Answer (score 2):

Just do this before you set all ::

```
$pro_url = 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/western-states-healthcare-group-2-0/view/Providers_Report?authtoken=b627006529f0d19852608be37d4bdf85&zc_ownername=nmormond&criteria=(Provider_Name=="Injury%20Treatment%20Centers%20Redwood")&scope=creatorapi';

$checkpro =curl_init($pro_url);

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_URL, $pro_url);

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);//standard i/o streams 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);// Turn off the server and peer verification 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 

curl_setopt($checkpro, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//Set to return data to string ($response) 

$datapro = curl_exec($checkpro);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($datapro);
```

Just added extra this line::

```
$checkpro =curl_init($pro_url);
```

Comment: I have try but not any luck, same problem

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
$checkpro =curl_init();
```

before setting all those parameters.

Also remove double quotes in your url

```
$pro_url = 'https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/western-states-healthcare-group-2-0/view/Providers_Report?authtoken=b627006529f0d19852608be37d4bdf85&zc_ownername=nmormond&criteria=(Provider_Name==Injury%20Treatment%20Centers%20Redwood)&scope=creatorapi';
```

Comment: Used this line But same problem

Comment: Double quotes remove then output is blank

Comment: @Gaurav I tested it on phpfiddle,so you might want to check your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/western-states-healthcare-group-2-0/view/Providers_Report?authtoken=b627006529f0d19852608be37d4bdf85&zc_ownername=nmormond&criteria=(Provider_Name%3D%3D%22Injury%2520Treatment%2520Centers%2520Redwood%22)&scope=creatorapi",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```